# Using Fragment in Android programming

Tags: java, android

I was practicing android app development watching the Youtube video.
The following code is exactly same with the result that the instructor coded except the import part.
Even though the code is same, mine has **4 errors** on it.(That's why I added some import part;;)

**Could you please look at it and teach me how to fix them?**
I saw similar questions in here but their solutions were not effective.

I got "activity_input.xml" to show the buttons and fragment.
This following code is on "InputActivity.java".
Three xml and java files for fragment.
which are "Fragment1.java", "Fragment2.java", "StartFragment.java", "fragment1.xml", "fragment2.xml", "start_fragment.xml".

The id of two button is "btn1", "btn2"
The id of layout that will display the fragment is "myFragment"

```
package com.example.money;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;

public class InputActivity extends Activity {

    Fragment fragment;
    Button btn1, btn2, btn3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_input);
        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); //Here error 1 on getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        StartFragment myFragment = new StartFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.myFragment, myFragment);  ////Here error 2 on add
        ft.commit();

        btn1.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);

    }

    Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Fragment newFragment;

            if (v == btn1)
                newFragment = new Fragment1();
            else if (v == btn2)
                newFragment = new Fragment2();
            else
                newFragment = new StartFragment();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            //Here error 3 on getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            //Here error 4 on replace
            transaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            transaction.commit();

        } 
    };
}
```

Comment: "Could you please look at it and teach me how to fix them?" -- No, this isn't how this works. You're starting out... if you can't resolve this yourself, you probably won't go very far. These are essential skills for you to learn, so you won't get frustrated every time you write a line of code. Aside from that, you haven't provided nearly enough information.

Comment: Sorry, I will look into it more;;

Comment: Why don't you look at each of your four errors individually and search specifically for that error message. Google and SO have a wealth of information. As it is, you haven't even identified what four errors you're getting, nor included all the code, so there's no way for anyone to help you.

Comment: i thinks error is already solved via my answer, why have you hold the question. the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code and organize your imports correctly in eclipse use control+shift+o.and chose correctly.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;

public class InputActivity extends Activity {

    Fragment fragment;
    Button btn1, btn2, btn3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.to_do_list);
        btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);

        android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager(); 
        android.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        StartFragment myFragment = new StartFragment();
        ft.add(myFragment,R.id.myFragment);  
        ft.commit();

        btn1.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(btnOnClickListener);

    }

    Button.OnClickListener btnOnClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Fragment newFragment;

            if (v == btn1)
                newFragment = new Fragment1();
            else if (v == btn2)
                newFragment = new Fragment2();
            else
                newFragment = new StartFragment();

            android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.myFragment, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            transaction.commit();

        } 
    };
}
```

Comment: Wow;; 3 errors are gone. There is one error on add (error 2) and the error code says "The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (StartFragment, int)"